How can I run my model created from DoCplex using a Cplex Cloud service?
I am working with a model in docplex and I want to run it with the Cplex Cloud version to integrate it into a microservice. What Cloud service can I use for this purpose and how can I write python code for this connection?

In the IBM Cloud you should use the WML (Watson Machine Learning) Service
See Scale DO execution on WML https://medium.com/@AlainChabrier/scale-do-execution-on-wml-9f577a981a15
